# How can I use resource-based authorization client-side in Blazor?

Tags: authorization, blazor-webassembly

I want to *check* authorization in the UI of a Blazor client app based on a resource (to not display certain UI options, etc.). The actual authorization is done in the API controller. However, I believe I need to access my database in order to do this, which I can't do client-side.

How do I reconcile this problem? How do I check authorization client-side?

Comment: Is resource-based authorization actually much rarer than I think? I don't understand how I'm seeing so many authorization examples than avoid the need to authorize based on resources.

Comment: It seems like devs have magical access to everything they need to run an auth check client-side, and I don't understand how everyone is achieving that.

Comment: Y'all wizards. I don't get it.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? One way I can think of is to actually have a client http dependency. So your policy / resource handler will use it to make a call to an api and that api can do the database stuff etc. Thoughts?

Comment: @TheMostCuriousThing - It's astonishing how much I relate to your comments.  Did you ever solve this?